# Jquery autocomplete -Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I m new to J query and was trying to get the auto complete  for one of my text boxes
here is the code of the asp x page.

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2"
 ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">  <title>jQuery UI
 Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>   <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   <script
 src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   <link
 rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
       "ActionScript",
       "Apple-script",
       "Asp",
       "BASIC",
       "C",
       "C++",
       "Closure",
       "COBOL",
       "ColdFusion",
       "Erlang",
       "Fortran",
       "Groovy",
       "Haskell",
       "Java",
       "JavaScript",
       "Lisp",
       "Perl",
       "PHP",
       "Python",
       "Ruby",
       "Scala",
       "Scheme"
     ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });   </script> </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
 Runat="Server"> <div id="searchcontainer" style="margin-top:50px">
 <div class="ui-widget">   <label for="tags">Tags: </label>   <input
 id="tags"> </div>
     <input id="btnSearch" type="button"  value="Search" style="margin-left:30px;border-radius: 5px; height: 30px; width:150px;
 box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #888888 ;" />
     <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel"  style="margin-left:30px;border-radius: 5px; height: 30px; width:150px;
 box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #888888 ;" /> </div> <div id="grdDisp"
 style="margin-top:30px">
     <asp:GridView ID="grdPurchaseHist" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="EU_DataTable" PageSize="10"
 OnPageIndexChanging="grdPurchaseHist_PageIndexChanging"
       runat="server" >
     </asp:GridView> </div> </asp:Content>
```

how ever when i view this page in the browser it does not work and it the Console it says 
object object has no method 'auto complete'.
I tried the similar .js files referenced in a new page with no content pages just to test it and it was working fine. Also when added the date picker ui it was working on the above page when referenced from the same .js files mentioned.

so i m not sure what have i done wrong in this web form or .js file as the auto complete ui is not working and the method is not found.
Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is getting wrong with your web page.Other than missing a closing tag on your input tag, every thing seems to be in place.

```
<input id="tags"> should be  <input id="tags" />
```

Most  browsers though are forgiving and you might get way with this.

I tried your code out of the box and it works.I have compiled a sample project for you  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y85atkixnbq1t1a/WebApplication8.zip) and make sure you have a similar set up using a master page.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.Actually i got what was going wrong your project worked for me fine but in mine case my master page was referencing some other .js files which were old and conflicting so removed them and all went awesome ..